# How do I resolve "X Error of failed request: GLXBadFBConfig" when installing iTunes using wine?

Tags: 20.04, wine, application-development, itunes

I installed wine in order to install iTunes. The iTunes icon is on the desktop but it won't open. with wine64 explorer I see iTunes.exe, however when clicking on it the following message in the Terminal appears.

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  0 ()
Serial number of failed request:  826
Current serial number in output stream:  826
```

Comment: Details needed. Which version of iTunes exactly? How it was installed with [wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?iId=1347&sClass=application)? Did you use [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2586-iTunes_12.html)?

Comment: iTunes 12.10.11 for Windows (Windows 64 bit). Fully followed this guide https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-itunes-on-linux-such-as-ubuntu-20-04-lts/ for wine installation.

Comment: Additional info needs to be in the question via an edit not as a comment so all can see.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369900/x-error-of-failed-request-glxbadfbconfig, it worked for me.