# X Error of failed request: GLXBadFBConfig

Tags: wine, opengl

Hi guys I hope you are well I recently installed Ubuntu because it calls me much attention but I had a problem when opening a game that is a launcher .exe the game does not have an installer I just have to open that .exe but when I open it with wine nothing happens then when I go to the command console and run it appears this error I am not very expert in the field but if someone could give me a solution I would appreciate it.

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  0 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  226
  Current serial number in output stream:  226
0104:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0104:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
```

I managed to change using a command which is the following: export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.5 after I used it the game program opened but the screen stays black and appears in the command console many codes saying the following

```
0160:err:d3d:wined3d_debug_callback 0x7f3b683f4cd0: "GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glGetUniformLocation(program not linked)".
```

Comment: Did you check the Wine site to see if his is a supported program that Wine can run?

Answer (score 3):

```
export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.5
```

fixed this bug for me. It's mentioned in https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50859

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50859 - it works for me. Seems to be a bug in "mesa" that has not been fixed for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the solution could have been mentioned in your answer also like someone else did after you: `export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.5`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was missing NVidia drivers. Check these things if you have an NVidia GPU:

1. Make sure you're using the proprietary driver instead of nouveau: look for "additional drivers" tab in Software & updates and select a line that says proprietary (and isn't a server one)
2. Make sure it's set up correctly (this is what I encountered this time): try running `sudo apt install --fix-broken` in case the last update failed for some reason
3. If you're using Flatpak to run Wine apps (using Bottles or another app): make sure the Flatpak NVidia drivers are also up to date with `flatpak update`